# Make Target dependent source list

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I want to compile two slightly different versions of my C code with one Makefile.

Basically I just need to add some Flags and some source files.

Right now I have a definition for my source list:

```
SRC := <adding stuff>
```

and generating my objects from that:

```
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o) $(ASRC:%.s=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)
```

The "all" target should compile normally, the "iomodule" target change the vars and call "all":

```
.PHONY: iomodule
iomodule: CDEFS := $(subst -DFD_MODULE, -DIO_MODULE, $(CDEFS))
#iomodule: SRC += $(subst $(SRC_DIR)/,,$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/iomod*.c))
iomodule: SRC += iomod_ring_proto.c
iomodule: OBJ += $(OBJ_DIR)/iomod_ring_proto.o
#iomodule: $(info $(SRC))
iomodule: all

all: dirs STM32F100RB_FLASH.ld $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $(TARGET).elf $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ)        $(LDLIBS)
        $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex   $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex
        $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin
```

I had expected that "info" would print SRC including "iomod_ring_proto.c" and that OBJ, since it's a recursive variable, would include the *.o file.

Strangely, "info" prints the list without the file and "iomod_ring_proto.c" is never compiled.
Yet I get a linker error that "objs/iomod_ring_proto.o" was not found. 
So it's not in the SRC list when I print it, not in the OBJ list when compiling, but it is in the OBJ list when linking? What's going on here??

Comment: What does `make -d` tell you?

Comment: @meaning-matters You probably meant `make -n`?

Comment: @devnull `-d` as in debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Make` commands like `$(info)` are evaluated immediately when the makefile is loaded. That's why it shows the "global" value of `$(SRC)`.

The problem with the linking not including your object file is that the the dependencies are *also* "evaluated" when the file is loaded. This means that for your `all` target, the dependencies are set as `OBJ` was when the file was loaded.

Comment: Specifically the GNU make manual section on target-specific variable says: _As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target's recipe_.  That means you can't use target-specific variables in the prerequisites list: they only work inside the recipe.

Comment: So is there a way to accomplish what I want to do? I want to add a few modules depending on make target. ty

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Adding source/objects files to a variable seems to work fine, at least in my version of make. Things like `$(info)` does not work like that though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The problem might be, that my c files are compiled by an implicit rule like "$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.c"? Even if I change OBJ to a "direct" variable (:=) I have the problem, that my C file is not compiled but the linker tries to link the corresponding O file :(